# How to subtract one audio wave from another?

Tags: c#, c++, c, aec

How to subtract one audio wave from another? In general and in C# (or if we cannot do it in C# in C/C++)

I have sound wave A and sound wave B (BTW: they are in PCM) 
I want to subtract B from A

What do I need? 
Open Source Libs (NOT GPL, but LGPL will be ok)
Tutorials on how to do such operation (with or without using libs)
Articles on this topic

PS: it’s all about AEC…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the samples are normalised to the same level, and are stored in a signed format such that the "zero level" is `0` or `0.0`, the answer is fairly simple:

```
S_C = (S_A / 2) - (S_B / 2);
```

for each sample `S_A` and `S_B` in A and B.

If you are using unsigned values for the samples then you will need to do more work: first, you need to convert them to a signed value with a zero centre (eg, if you have 16 bit unsigned samples, subtract 32768 from each), then apply the formula, then convert them back to the unsigned format.  Be careful of overflow - here's an example of how to do the conversions for the aforementioned 16 bit samples:

```
#define PCM_16U_ZERO 32768

short pcm_16u_to_16s(unsigned short u)
{
    /* Ensure that we never overflow a signed integer value */
    return (u < PCM_16U_ZERO) ? (short)u - PCM_16U_ZERO : (short)(u - PCM_16U_ZERO);
}

unsigned short pcm_16s_to_16u(short s)
{
    /* As long as we convert to unsigned before the addition, unsigned arithmetic
       does the right thing */
    return (unsigned short)s + PCM_16U_ZERO;
}
```

Comment: Subtracting two signals is the same as adding one signal to a 180-degree phase-shifted version of the other.  The division by two keeps the power (level) of the resulting signal the same as the individual input signals - if you don't do it, then your resulting signal will be effectively amplified by 6dB (and is likely to clip).

Comment: Intuitively, I have a problem with this.  Suppose `S_B` is all 0's (silent).  In that case, you'd want the result, `S_C`, to be identical to `S_A`.  Your signed formula causes `S_C` to be half `S_A`.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723563/acoustic-echo-cancellation-aec-in-wpf-with-c Asks a similar question and has an accepted answer. The suggested library does have some sort of Echo Cancellation I think.

Unfortunately I haven't used any open source audio libraries. I have used [Fmod](http://www.fmod.org/) to process audio before, I don't remember there being any AEC in it, but you can get access to the raw audio as it processes it and run your own code on it.

Comment: Serves me right for not looking at the poster. Sorry about that.

Comment: I guess he's after the *Taxonomist* badge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aec